# Why week-picker is undefined?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using a custom build of jQuery UI 1.9.2 and this is `undefined`:

```
$('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseover', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
```

Comment: instead of `.live()` use `.on()`

Comment: it recognizes it but doesn't work as .live()

Comment: Consider adding some more code so that we can see the structure of your HTML that jQuery is looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed in the 1.9 update. Use event delegation for the same behaviour:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr', function(e) {
    $(e.target).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover');
});
```

Note also that `this` in this handler will be bound to `document`. To get the originating element, use `event.target`